# Rails link_to with empty/blank name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make a link that has the `name` part in the link_to api `link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil)` empty or blank. The code `link_to("Default", default_path, :class => "default")` results in `<a class="default" href="/default">Default</a>` but I want it to be `<a class="default" href="/default"> </a>` instead.

Passing `nil` into the link_to tag `link_to(nil, default_path, :class => "default")` only results in a url path being passed into where the `name` should be `<a class="default" href="/default">/default</a>`

What should I pass to make sure I achieve this result: `<a class="default" href="/default"> </a>` ?

Comment: do `link_to("", default_path, :class => "default")`

Comment: @ArupRakshit who would have thought -.- Thanks, fixed it